# Hive External Table Schema Reconnection

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, data-warehouse

Suppose I deleted the schema for existing hive external table by dropping the table, the data still exists in location.

Then I recreated external table with same schema on same location of existing data.

1. Will I get result while querying?
2. If not what to do to get result of queries?
3. Can we connect to derby DB in hive anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You should have tried this as you already know that file still exists even after dropping the table.

I have a table - time_file;

```
hive> show create table time_file;
OK
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `time_file`(
  `tm_dim_key` string,
  ......
  ....)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'field.delim'='|',
  'serialization.format'='|')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'maprfs:/user/vijay/scm';
```

Drop table -

```
hive> drop table if exists time_file;
OK
Time taken: 0.1 seconds
```

After dropping the table file still exists in hadoop location -

```
hive> !hadoop fs -ls /user/supplychainadmin/alb_supply_chain_ext
    > ;
Found 1 items
-rwxr-xr-x   3 scm scm   74163231 2019-02-07 04:21 /user/vijay/scm/time_file1.dat
```

after creating table again -

we can query data

```
hive> select * from time_file limit 1;
OK
735918                                          735918  ABS Fiscal Year  2016           11280   50343524        50343524                                    Year     02-25-17        25                                                      1       ABS Fiscal Year  2016                           1       Saturday    7
Time taken: 0.106 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You deleted the schema for existing hive external table by dropping the table, the data still exists in location.

Then if you recreated external table with same schema on same location of existing data.

ANS:1)You Will get result as you were getting.
Droping External hive table only removes metadata from configured RDBMS megastore.

ANS:3) Yes you get default derby DB in embedded mode or if you want derby DB explicitly 
in distributed mode , it can be configured in *hive.site.xml* file